# SQL Server Express - Error When trying to attach with VIsual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, windows

[image: Error Message]

When I Try to Put my Database (SQL Server Express) into Visual Studio to a Text box , I get this error , What am I doing Wrong?

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It looks really clear to me -- you are using incompatible software.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm Using Microsoft SQL Server 2017 and Visual Studio Community 2017. I simply don't understand why I cannot Connect it to my small login project I have

Comment: It looks like you may have multiple SQL Server versions installed. Connect to your express instance and run `SELECT @@VERSION;` to verify the target SQL Server version.

Comment: @DanGuzman I'm sorry Im a beginner haha, I don't know where to run your command, sorry for my dumbness

Comment: From a command-prompt, run `SQLCMD -S .\SQLEXPRESS -Q"SELECT @@VERSION;` to verify your SQL Express version. If that is SQL 2017, you are trying to attach the file to a different instance in VS. Run `SQLServerManager14.msc` to view the installed SQL Server instances.

Answer (score 1):

The `.mdf` file you have is of internal database version **869** - this is SQL Server **2017**. But you're trying to attach it to a SQL Server **2016** instance, which only supports databases up to internal version 852.

This will **never** work - SQL Server `.mdf` files are **NOT** backwards compatible, you **cannot** with any trick, workaround, hack or anything else ever get a SQL Server **2017** database file attached (or restored to) a SQL Server **2016** instance.

Comment: so How may I fix this? how do I get a SQL Server 2017 instance?

Comment: @S.Stone: you can download SQL Server 2017 from Microsoft's site and install it locally on your machine - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Comment: Express
SQL Server 2017 Express is a free edition of SQL Server, ideal for development and production for desktop, web, and small server applications. @marc_s This is the versuon I've installed yesterday